# nextDouble error symbol: method nextDouble

Tags: java

symbol: method nextDouble

nextDouble "error"

Can any one help me to fix that ?

```
    double fahrenheit;

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Fahrenheit degre : ");

    fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();

    double Celsius = 5/9 * (fahrenheit-32);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " in Celsius : " + Celsius);
```

Comment: BTW you've got an integer division issue - use `double Celsius = 5/9.0 * (fahrenheit-32);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'e confusing `String` with `java.util.Scanner`. Parse the string returned from `showInputDialog`

```
fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(input);
```